# JavaCV - Running Examples

Tags: eclipse, macos, javacv

I'm a bit of an amateur developer and I'm currently messing around with JavaCV and Eclipse on my Mac.

I'm trying to get the FaceRecorgnition to work but I don't really know how to install this into Eclipse properly.

I've created a new Java Project, and I've imported the 'JavaCPP', 'JavaCV-Mac', and 'JavaCV' libraries.

I then created a package and called it 'mvn', then created a class and C/P the 'FaceRecorgnition' java into that class and then try and run it. I then get this error:

```
Oct 24, 2012 10:17:22 PM mvn.FaceRecognition learn
INFO: ===========================================
Oct 24, 2012 10:17:22 PM mvn.FaceRecognition learn
INFO: Loading the training images in data/all10.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/all10.txt (No such file or directory)
    at mvn.FaceRecognition.loadFaceImgArray(FaceRecognition.java:317)
    at mvn.FaceRecognition.learn(FaceRecognition.java:97)
    at mvn.FaceRecognition.main(FaceRecognition.java:789)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/all10.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at mvn.FaceRecognition.loadFaceImgArray(FaceRecognition.java:244)
    ... 2 more
```

I don't fully understand imports and SDKs fully yet, so be easy.

Thanks.

Comment: heres a link to the JavaCV too - http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Comment: BTW, you should also try the new [FaceRecognizer](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) module from OpenCV instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not about missing libraries, but a missing .txt file.
It seems like the all10.txt file is not included in the JavaCV download.

Check out http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html under the heading 
**"How to use the offline cmd-based FaceRec system:"**

You find the all10.txt file in his zip facerecExample_ORL.zip and the faces needed in the zip 
Cambridge_FaceDB.zip

Create a data folder where FaceRecognition.java is. 
Put the .txt files in that folder as well as the Cambridge_FaceDB folder:

```
samples/
  FaceRecognition.java  
  data/
    all10.txt
    Cambridge_FaceDB/
```